# Proof using the AM-GM inequality.

Tags: inequality

I've been studying for my upcoming exams and I came across this exercise in the AM-GM inequality section:

If $a_n = \sqrt[n]{a}$ , $a \in \mathbb{R}$ , $ a > 0$ , $n \in \mathbb{N}$ then prove that:

> $$
> \dfrac{na}{1 + na} < a_n < 1 + \dfrac{a}{n}.
> $$

I've been trying to prove this for the past few hours but I am completely stuck at this point. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A start:** Consider the numbers $1,1,1,\dots,1$ ($n-1$ of them) and $a$. Their arithmetic mean is $\frac{n-1+a}{n}$ and their geometric mean is $\sqrt[n]{a}$. Now note that $1+\frac{a}{n}\gt \frac{n-1+a}{n}$.

Comment: Too tired. Thanks for the fast answer.

Comment: You are welcome. It is only half an answer, I am leaving the other half to you.

Comment: I solved it. The rest of the proofs in the book misdirected me and I completely missed the obvious approach.

Comment: Good. The type of "trick" I used comes up medium often.